# nginx location double urlencode an encoded URL

Tags: nginx

we are building a nginx reverse proxy for aws S3, our configuration list bellow

```
location ~* ^/chn/apkpack/(.*) {
    set $s3_bucket        'xxx.s3.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn';
    set $url_full         '';
    if ($request_uri ~ "^.*/(.+)$"){
        set $url_full         'cdn/chn/apkpack/$1';
    }
    echo $request_uri;
    echo $url_full;
    ...
 }
```

for the URL: `http://test.com/chn/apkpack/yjmt%EF%BC%88j%E3%81%AEl%EF%BC%89_1.08.00_12_signed_chn_1_915b96a7b88f7df6.apk`

the result would be

```
/chn/apkpack/yjmt%EF%BC%88j%E3%81%AEl%EF%BC%89_1.08.00_12_signed_chn_1_915b96a7b88f7df6.owk
cdn/chn/apkpack/yjmt%25EF%25BC%2588j%25E3%2581%25AEl%25EF%25BC%2589_1.08.00_12_signed_chn_1_915b96a7b88f7df6.apk
```

our URL are double encoded， what we need is don't urlencode the URL again.

how to solve this?